# Set max width of Select when it expands?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the following...

http://jsfiddle.net/WvgSw/7/

I'd like to set the max width so that when it is expands (when you click it) rather than the menu growing to larger than 180px it remains a max of 180px and the text simply cuts off. How would I achieve this?

**NOTE:** I would prefer the markup in Javascript, not CSS. I am aware of max-width in CSS.

Comment: What about adding `multiple="mutliple"` to the drop down list?

Answer (score 2):

Check the following code:

**Page**

```
    <select id='select' style='max-width:180px;'>
  <option class="maxwidth" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option class="maxwidth" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option class="maxwidth" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option class="maxwidth" value="LARGER THAN 180PX  TEST TEST TEST TEST">LARGER THAN 180PX  TEST TEST TEST TE</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.maxwidth
{
    max-width:100px;
}
```

I have updated the code on the link you have provided.

http://jsfiddle.net/WvgSw/347/

*Note: please mark the correct answer and Vote For it.*

Comment: Although this is correct, it's not exactly what I was looking for. I was it done in Javascript.

Comment: hey how is this get upvoted? wrong answer, try to change it for 1px, doesn't affect anything. and obviously cant mark this one as correct @Shivkant

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot limit the width of the drop down of a regular `select` control. You will need to use custom controls, either built by yourself or using other packages.

DevExpress, and probably the likes of Infragistics, provides this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the width of the select box to auto

```
menu.style.width = "auto";
```

This way it wont expand when you click it, but it wont cut off the largest entry.

~Amrish

Comment: No, you see I want it to ALWAYS remain 180px and not expand depending on items.